# Is there a way to open all items in a folder in Chrome on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there a way to open all items in a folder in Chrome on Mac OS X? In Windows you can go to a folder in the bookmarks, right-click and select open all in tabs, but in Mac OS X this is not possible. Right click doesn't do anything. Is there an alternate way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Chrome are you using? It works here on 4.0.249.49 on Snow Leopard.

[image]

Comment: I'm always current, my issue was trying on the macosx top bar bookmark menu, where right click doesn't do anything. I've enabled the bookmark bar like you did and using that now.

Comment: its called secondary click, for standard setting in trackpad this means two finger click.